# Not retrieving a OneToOne relationtionship Object in Spring Data JPA CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following implementation of Crud Repository, where I need to find if *MyObject* contains a reference to *OtherObject*.

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Long> {
    List<MyObject> findByOtherObject(Long id);
}
```

This is how I map my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
public class MyObject {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_id")
    private OtherObject otherObject;
}
```

And the error I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [3] did not match expected type
```

This shows that I am mapping incorrectly between my Entity and my Repository. But I do not want to change the name of the column.

It does not work if I change the repository method to *findByObject_Id*. Any suggestion?

Comment: did you try `findByOtherObject_Id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
findByOtherObjectId(Long id)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but the way you put it on the comment: findByOtherObject_Id. It is like first it looks for that object and then it goes for the property inside that object.

Comment: yes it is looking for the object related by the oneToOne relation whose inned id object matches the given parameter